# FileNotFoundException using Notepad

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which I install and run using Windows Prompt (console). And every time I run it I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
public Properties getConfigProperties() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(loader.getResource("config.properties").getFile());
        config.load(new FileReader(file));
        return config;
}
```

Or `NullPointerException` if I use `classpath:config.properties`.

`config.properties` file is inside *`/src/main/resources/`* folder.

Also if I run the project in the IDE it completes successfully without any exceptions occurring.

So what's the problem when I use the console command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insteed of

```
File file = new File(loader.getResource("config.properties").getFile());
```

use

```
File file = new File(loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

Another way to get your xml file loaded in your classpath is by using the Spring Framework as below:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
resolver.getResources("classpath*:your/package/**/config.properties");
```

Comment: Ok, `getResourceAsStream()` works. But can you explain why?

Comment: It's most certainly a classLoader problem. Eclipse IDE has it's own classLoader that,when you call `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`, get the file from `workspace/test/target/classes/config.properties`. But when you run it from command line, the classloader try to get it from `<JAR_FOLDER>/YOUR_JAR.jar!config.properties` and this path is not valid to create a **java.io.File** and throws a `FileNotFoundException`